# How to stop ProxyPassMatch (mod_proxy) to disable directory listings (mod_autoindex)?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, centos7, mod-proxy

Recently I compiled php 5.3.11 with fpm support, and as soon I get apache up using

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/$1"
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.sthml welcome.html /index.php index.php
```

It makes php to work fine, but stops directory listing; on the other hand I have:

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.php.*">
     SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/"
     DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.shtml welcome.html index.php /index.php
     Options +Indexes +Multiviews +Includes +FollowSymLinks
</FilesMatch>
```

And it works backwards as ProxyPassMatch, everything works but php breaks.

I have my php-fpm.conf directive: listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

I tried

> listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock

But it happens all the same.

Is that it isn't possible to use Options +Indexes +Multiviews +Includes +FollowSymLinks altogether with ProxyPassMatch?

Why isn't my FilesMatch directive working? I even have tried to setHandler the full path

And believe me, I have tried almost everything I have found using google, server fault and stack overflow!!!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Options related to Indexes and the likes make no sense inside Files/FilesMatch, it is intended for "directories".

You should try something like:

```
<Directory /path/to/documentroot>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.shtml welcome.html index.php
     Options +Indexes +Multiviews +Includes +FollowSymLinks
    <FilesMatch \.php>
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/"
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Note: Indexes will show a directory listing.

Comment: It seems my error is the chroot configuration for php-fpm, that was set to '/var/www'.  I changed it to "/" and worked, but right now I am still trying to figure out how it works with apache and how to configure it to have a safe server.  It is not very important since I am working on a development/test local machine, but I will keep reading.  Right now I believe that somehow chroot php-fpm's conf depends on DocumentRoot apache httpd's configuration.  Anyway, thanks for your help, it helped me to go on the right direction.